# Git - When branching off BranchA, how do I reset my new branch BranchB so it doesn't have any BranchA content?

Tags: git

I have been doing a lot of work on BranchA.

I now want to create a new local branch BranchB and pull down this remote branch from GitHub.

However, doing git checkout -b BranchB will still have all the changes I made to BranchA.

How do I reset this branch so it has nothing in it, so I can pull a clean BranchB from GitHub?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming BranchB is on the server, just do `git checkout BranchB` (without the `-b` option). This will create BranchB and have it automatically track origin/BranchB. If you have already created the "wrong" BranchB locally, make sure to delete it with `git branch -d BranchB` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch which starts from a certain point of your history with this command:

```
git checkout -b BranchB <sha1>
```

This command does 2 things:

- It creates a local branch called BranchB which starts from <sha1>
- HEAD switchs to this branch with your working tree

Then you can push and track it:

```
git push origin BranchB --set-upstream
```

Note that <sha1> could be :

- origin/master
- origin/master~1
- BranchA~2
- actually, any commit's sha1

If you already have a "bad" local or remote branch which name is BranchB, you can delete them:

```
git push origin :BranchB  # Deletes the remote branch origin/BranchB
git branch -d BranchB     # Deletes the local branch BranchB (if merged, no risk to loose data)
git branch -D BranchB     # Deletes the local branch BranchB (force for not merged branches)
```